# Sum and Group By in Linq to Entities

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-3.5

I'm trying to get sum of some values by grouping and I'm stuck. This is the sample structure of my table:

[image]

What I want to get is:

**User name, project name, total work time of project users, grouped by user name and project name.**

The trick is that I need to display a zero or a null value if a user is in a project and the user doesn't have any work time yet.

Example result should be like this:

```
Username  Project  Total Time
User1     Project1 15
User1     Project2 --
User2     Project1 10
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Your model has no navigation properties, did you do it intentionally?

Comment: Yes it's not the complete model, just a sample.

Comment: If you add navigational properties (for ex. user.Projects, project.Users), LINQ should be much simple, than joining by hands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This scary select would work, once you add references (navigational properties)

```
db.Users.SelectMany(
    x=> x.Projects
           .Select(i=>
                  new
                  {
                     User = x.Name,
                     Project = i.Name,
                     WorkTime = (int?)i.UserWorkTimes.Sum(t=>t.WorkTime)
                   })
    );
```

My assumptions are

1. WorkTime is of int type.
2. Nav.property from Projects To ProjectUserWorkTimes is called **UserWorkTimes**
3. Nav.property from Users to Projects is called **Projects**